# How to inflater layout in Alert Dialog box and send data from input to restApi through adapter

Tags: android, android-volley, android-alertdialog, layout-inflater

Having problem inflating layout in AlertDialog box in On bindViewHolder Adapter, It is giving me an error when declaring and creating the object of the LayoutInflater.

I searched a lot about it but couldn't find a single solution, Actually, I'm inflating layout which will consist an input from and send data as params to RestAPI. Please help me to solve the error.

In case I get the layout then where should I do the post operation(in adapter or main class? pls help I'm using StringRequest and URL and volley for network)

Adapter code:

```
holder.editbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"edit"+listClient.getCustomername(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());

            LayoutInflater inflater =v.getLayoutInflater;//Getting Errorrrr

           builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_dialog, null));

            builder.setTitle("Client Status update")
                    .setMessage("client name:"+listClient.getCustomername())

                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Log.i("Result","Success");
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Log.i("Result","UnSuccess");
                        }
                    })
                    .show();

        }
```

//status method in main class
    public void status(){

```
    final String status=;//how to get the string from the adapter dialog input??
    StringRequest stringRequest =new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URLs.URL_status_change,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try{
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }


                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(Track_issues_client.this,volleyError.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }){

        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("status",status);
            return params;
        }


    };
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}
```

Adapter code:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"edit"+listClient.getCustomername(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
            View mView =  LayoutInflater.from(v.getRootView().getContext()).inflate(R.layout.edit_dialog, null);
           // String a =status.setText(listClient.getStatus().toString());
            builder.setView(mView);

            builder.setTitle("Client Status update")
                    .setMessage("client name:"+listClient.getCustomername())

                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            c.status();

                            Log.i("Result","Success");
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Log.i("Result","UnSuccess");
                        }
                    })
                    .show();

        }
```

Comment: what error you get. share stacktrace.

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater =v.getLayoutInflater;//Getting Errorrrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution.

```
  holder.editbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"edit"+listClient.getCustomername(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());

      View mView =  LayoutInflater.from(v.getRootView().getContext()).inflate(R.layout.edit_dialog, null);

       builder.setView(mView);

        builder.setTitle("Client Status update")
                .setMessage("client name:"+listClient.getCustomername())

                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override 
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.i("Result","Success");
                    } 
                }) 
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override 
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.i("Result","UnSuccess");
                    } 
                }) 
                .show(); 

    }
```

Comment: it shows me the layout in dialog ,now how to post the value to restApi ??

Comment: Just call API in button clicks and pass values. that's all

Comment: i never tried in adapter but did in main class by creating method and SringRequest post

Comment: Please remove that answer. you should edit the question.